# Are two questions with no answers not duplicates even if they're the same?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, flagging

This is a two-parter (but related):

1. Has it always been the policy that a duplicate is not a duplicate if neither question has been answered?
2. Does this make the most sense in terms of drawing attention to and getting a response for an as-yet unanswered query?

These two questions re. editing groups in Outlook.com seem pretty identical to mr and were asked about a month apart:

- [Outlook.com sends emails to deleted group members](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44864/outlook-com-sends-emails-to-deleted-group-members?rq=1)
- [Removing a contact from a group in outlook.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44193/removing-a-contact-from-a-group-in-outlook-com)

I had posted this in chat, but the great (no sarcasm) Jacob Jan recommended I give it a whirl here in meta...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously most SE moderators close questions as duplicates if it was asked before. Recently, an announcement was made by SE Inc.

> Duplicates now focus on redirection to the answers you need
>
> All dupes now must point to an answered question, and the new language focuses on getting you answers

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/

Comment: Got it. I'm just wondering what the best way is for the question to be answered for the most people in the end (I cam also imagine there being a slippery slope of unanswered question repetition...) I'll have to read the blog discussion more closely!